# Первая нормальная форма

Tags: база-данных

Есть собственно определение нормальной формы:таблица находится в первой нормальной форме если атрибуты атомарны, нет повторяющихся групп и все строки различны.С атомарностью атрибутов более или менее всё понятно если нельзя разбить на несколько не потеряв осмысленности(фамилию к примеру никак не разобьёшь т.к потеряется смысл), а вот что имеется под повторяющимися группами и различностью строк мне не совсем ясно, желательно привести пример.
И неплохо было бы показать как собственно привести к нормальной форме на примере.

Comment: про повторяющиеся группы с примером https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: нет одинаковых строк - нет двух строк в которых все поля были бы одинаковы. грубо говоря, если таблица из двух полей имя и фамилия то не может быть двух записей Иван Иванов

Comment: @Mike посмотрел статью, и поправьте если что не так, но как я понял повторяющаяся группа это там где не одно значение на пересечение строки и столбца?
И ещё вопрос пишут про функциональную зависимость и что-то я не совсем понимаю этот термин,мне кажется это что-то типа как в математике зная икс подставим в уравнение и получим игрик или как-то так?

Comment: Про повторяющуюся группу да. Функциональная зависимость, да, как в математике, значение "функции" одинаково при одинаковых аргументах. Т.е. значение одного столбца может быть выведено из значения другого. "Выведено" - не обязательно вычислено по формуле. Например у вас таблица с ежемесчными выплатами работникам и там помимо табельного номера еще и ФИО и год рождения, которые всегда одни и те же для одного табельного номера (изменение фамилии в расчет не берем, это точно зарплаты не касается)

Answer (score 0):

Как я это понимаю:

```
Фирма   Модели
"BMW"   "M5, X5M, M1"   // <- нарушение атомарности
"Nissan""GT-R"

Фирма   Модели
"BMW"   "M5"   // <- нарушение одинаковые строки
"BMW"   "M5"   // <- (избыток информации)
"Nissan""GT-R"

Фирма   Модели
"BMW или Lada"  "7"   // <- нарушение скалярной величины BMW или Lada 
"Moskvich и Volga" "24"  // не описывает однозначно
"Nissan""GT-R"
```